# Max retry error while requesting auth token in docusign api

Tags: python, python-3.6, docusignapi, python-3.5

In docusign version 3.1.0, python version 3.5 and 3.6 in sandbox mode, I'm getting following error:

```
MaxRetryError at /return_url/8a2108d2-ee01-4c1a-ae53-47d305a92988/
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='https', port=443): 
  Max retries exceeded with url: //account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token
 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection
 object at 0x7fe15ca63438>: Failed to establish a new connection:
 [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

Comment: no enough information here. Can you provide the code you are running? this seems like a network issue, but hard to say much with very little info

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, it looks like you're not specifying the URL correctly.

You should be doing a POST to https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token

It looks like you're close to that but not correct. Eg, why does the error message show that `host='https'` -- The host should be `account-d.docusign.com` or `https://account-d.docusign.com`

Are you using an OAuth Authorization Code Grant library for Python? I always recommend using a library. See our [eg-03-python-auth-code-grant](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-python-auth-code-grant) example which uses the flask_oauthlib.